# C++: Error when inputting the second input after have done the first one already

Tags: c++, input

I try to write the program to input a series of numbers and input how many numbers I want to sum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    vector<int> number;

    cout << "Please enter some number (press '|' at prompt to stop):\n";
    while (cin >> num)
        number.push_back(num);

    int n, sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter how many of the numbers you wish to sum, starting from the first:\n";
    cin >> n;
    
}
```

But when I input some number and stop my first input with **'|'**, then it outputs the line **"Please enter how many of..."** and ends the compiler without inputting the variable **n**.

Comment: when you put `|` into cin for a number, pretty sure this will constitute an error which you do not clear and gets re-read in the `cin >> n` line.

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense to prompt for the number of numbers to read, then read that many? Or to simply keep track in your `while` loop.

Comment: Describe your input specification.  Is each individual number to be entered on a single prompt?  (_i.e._ user types a number, presses enter, continue until they just type `|` and press enter)...  Or, can the user enter a bunch of numbers on one or more lines, separating values by whitespace or other characters?  In either case, how do you expect the program to handle invalid input?  I generally recommend `std::getline` to read one line of input at a time into a `std::string` and then use `std::istringstream` to process that input.  This approach has served me well for a very long time.

Comment: @paddy Thanks bro, your recommendation works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add cin.ignore() before taking in last argument, to ignore the extra characters that gets added to input stream (when you hit '\n' to input your value, it gets added to input stream and also other invalid inputs you may additionally add on same line). Probably want to add in cin.clear() to reset stream state beforehand as well.

```
#include <limits> // also include limits header

int main()
{
    int num;
    vector<int> number;

    cout << "Please enter some number (press '|' at prompt to stop):\n";
    while (cin >> num)
        number.push_back(num);

    int n, sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter how many of the numbers you wish to sum, starting from the first:" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin >> n;
}
```

Also, please note that prompt will stop no matter what noninteger you input for while loop.

Comment: The OP may also wish to keep a tally of how many numbers are input in the while loop and check that against `n`, in the event the user running this program inputs two numbers and then specifies they want to sum the first three.